# ¿Qué es esta variable en Storage de Laravel?

Tags: laravel, local-storage, filesystem

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por mucho que googleo, no encuentro una explicación de qué es esa variable... ¿para qué sirve? ¿que debe de contener?, etc..

Alguien podría explicarme?

En mi aplicación yo genero un nombre de archivo propio (que utilizo para después mostrarlo en la página y le paso una ruta dónde debe de guardarlo. Pero utilizo el método storeAs() de Storage.
Grácias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `put` recibe como primer parámetro la ruta y nombre con el que se guardará el archivo y como segundo parámetro el archivo como tal (osea el contenido).

Imaginemos que deseamos guardar una imagen de nombre `imagen_A.jpg` pero con el nombre `imagen_B.jpg` en el subdirectorio `imagenes`. Para este caso podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
// recibimos la imagen_A.jpg de algún modo
// imaginemos que viene a través de un request.
// la foto que estamos recibimento se llama imagen_A.jpg
// esta imagen la estamos enviando con el nombre de variable `imagen`
$imagen = $request->file('imagen');

// ahora la almacenamos con el nombre imagen_b.jpg dentro del direcotorio `imagenes`
Storage::disk('uploads')->put('imagenes/imagen_b.jpg', $imagen);
// quedando así: imagenes>imagen_b.jpg
```

Comment: Ah ok, $imagen, se crea el archivo y $imagen contiene el contenido del archivo paa asignarselo al archivo que está creando... entendido! Grácias!